# Can cURL accept connection request and verify certificates?

Tags: c++11, curl

I wonder is there any possibility that cURL to accept a connection request from the server and verify certificates, requested ports by listening on some port?. If in a case of success, receives data from the server until the server closes the connection.

Backgound : C++11

Thanks
Uma

Comment: By definition, an entity initiating the request is the client, and one listening for and accepting requests is the server. In light of this, it's not clear what you mean by *"accept a connection request from the server"*. cURL is the client library, it has no provision for listening or accepting incoming requests.

Comment: nope, listening for incoming connections is not a job for curl. try googling "simple http socket server c++ example"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the reply. Yes, I agree with the client, server definition.  What I want to achieve is " Push message receiver".  I get messages from a remote machine(server), and here server initiates connections and sends messages after successful connection.  I am bit skeptic in achieving this using cURL.  Now I am clear that cURL is not the right one for my goal.